# whea uncorrectable error | unexpected kernel mode trap | page fault in nonpaged area

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, bsod

I always get a BLUESCREEN with one of those error messages...

I googled it: hardware-error.

I already tried to change the psu, RAM, SSD and took out the gpu; non-effectiv.

I tried clean-installing windows on the pc, and tried also installing windows on another pc on a ssd, and then putting this ssd in the malufunctioning pc; also non-effectiv.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: A WHEA error is normally a driver error. Windows normally updates many drivers, so based on your post it may be the SSD driver.

Comment: @John Yeah but the problem is, that I already tried installing different versions of windows... I also reinstalled the original HDD.

Comment: Perhaps find drivers for each device (Audio, Video, Network, and possibly BIOS)

Comment: @John I'm wondering about why it worked earlier... Where do I get those driver-files? How am I able to put them up on my pc; Do i have to put them in the System32 folder?

Comment: Driver updates do not (to my knowledge and experience) land in the Windows system folder WinSXS perhaps

Comment: can you post the details of the error from the event viewer. I was getting this error when I was "tuning" (undervolting cores) my CPU - it was totally expected by the way, until I got the tuning right.

Comment: @JaromandaX The problem is, that I don't even get into the OS... There is always a bluescreen before I even get to login.

Comment: @PeterAndres - yeah, sorry, wasn't thinking!! You haven't done any CPU tweaking in the BIOS?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nah... I already tried resetting the bios. Didn't work.